# Kafka: how does consumer offsets work with dynamically created group ids?

Tags: apache-kafka

In Kafka, each consumer group is represented by a unique group.id property. Each consumer group manages their own offset (stored in __consumer_offsets topic). What happens to this offset if I always start my consumer service with a dynamically generated group.id value?

Will this new consumer group always read from the beginning of the topic since it has no offset, or will 'auto.offset.reset' take effect?

Comment: I think that dynamically created group IDs only make sense with the `latest` configuration and only if you want to process current messages and don't care about missing previous messages. So make sure your usage scenario does not require at-least-once.

Comment: thanks for clarifying this, I want to also process missing previous messages, so I may just hard code the different group ids in the services so when they restart, they will remember the offset

Comment: I usually define group ID == service name so each service has its own single group ID (no matter how many topics it consumes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generate a new `group.id` each time your application starts, the consumer will rely on `auto.offset.reset` to find its starting position. This is because there won't be any offsets stored as this is a new group.

With `auto.offset.reset`, you can instruct consumers to either start from the beginning with `earliest` or end with `latest` of the logs.

Note that at startup you can also control the position in your application logic and explicitly seek to an arbitrary position based on whatever you want.

A relatively common pattern is to start from a position derived on time, for example seek to 1 hour ago or start of the day. This can be done using [`offsetsForTimes()`](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)) and [`seek()`](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,long)).